# Prove: $\exists !$ $t \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall s \in \mathbb{N}$, $(t-9)s = 0$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I have a basic uniqueness proof to help me work on form: It should be obvious by simple inspection that the statement is true for t=9 and only for t=9. So my proof was this:

Let $t=9$ then $9-9=0$, and $0 \cdot s=0$

For the uniqueness, assume that $w,x \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the property. Then $(w-9)s = (x-9)s$, implying that $w=s$. Thus there is at most one solution.

Apparently I had a problem with the existence part of the proof, I need help stating it more succinctly, please.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a problem with your existence proof, except that you haven't quantified $s$. It is best to say "Let $s \in \mathbb{N}$..." and then conclude that in fact the statement holds for all $s \in \mathbb{N}$ as $s$ was chosen arbitrarily. In your uniqueness argument you might have to be a bit careful - if $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$, then you need to first assert that $(w-9)s=(x-9)s$ for some _nonzero_ $s$ so that you can cancel and conclude that $w=x$.

Comment: It is the uniqueness part that is problematic, To prove it, suppose that $(w-9)s=0$ for all $s$. Let $s=1$. Then $w-9=0$ and therefore $w=9$.

Answer (score 2):

A product is equal to zero iff either or both of its factors is zero. So in this case $(t-9)=0$ or $s=0$. However $s$ varies in $\mathbb{N}$ so is not always zero, thus it follows that $(t-9)=0\iff t=9$, which proves existence and uniqueness.